# Network shared folder access across nodes in azure service fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, network-share

I have a service fabric cluster on Azure with 5 nodes. For testing, I have not configured any firewalls. I need to share a folder from one node such that it can be accessible by Network Service account from other node.

Though I set share permissions to network service, I always get access denied. However the local user account on the other node is able to access the shared folder

Comment: So seems like there is no networking issues here. Just a permission issue. What access policies have you tried setting for the permissions?

Comment: I have tried adding Network Service with read/write permissions. Also, just to test I added Everyone with read/write access. Even with this other nodes are not able to access the shared folder while running under network service account

Comment: Thanks for that. I am checking with the SF team offline to see if there is something special we are missing. Will update once I hear back from them.

Comment: I did talk with the SF team and there is nothing special you have to do to share folders across nodes. So whatever the issue is, it does seem to be just a authentication error. As a side note, why are you trying to do a shared folder? Kind of an odd thing to do in a SF environment.

Comment: We are moving our service from on-prem to azure.

Comment: Basically there is a folder in one of the nodes which needs to be accessed by the service from other nodes. Since the service runs under network account, we had set the folder permissions to allows network service access and it was working fine on-prem. Trying to achieve the same on azure SF

Comment: Got it. Personally I would suggest looking into using Azure Files instead of a fileshare on a node https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction nodes in Azure if they have an issue will automatically recover so this could mean the file share if located on a single node might not be available 100% of the time.